# 403 Forbidden when trying to change multiple bots statuses. (discord py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Whenever i try to change a bot's status using requests (python) in discord i get 403 Forbidden.
(Note: im trying to change multiple bots statuses so i can't use the normal client.change_presence function)
*Code:*

```py
import discord, json
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import threading
from threading import Thread
from libs import (
  core
)
from libs.core import *


class Misc(commands.Cog, name="Miscellanous Commands"):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.tokens = core.tokens

  @commands.command(name="status", description="Available statuses are: online, dnd (do not disturb), offline, idle")
  async def status(self, ctx, *, args):
    """Changes the bots statuses"""
    args = args.lower()
    for token in self.tokens:
      if args == "on" or args == "online":
        try:
          result = requests.patch("https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/settings", headers=core.mainHeaders(token), data=json.dumps({"status":"online"}))
        except:
          pass
            
      if args == "dnd" or args == "do not disturb":
        try:
          result = requests.patch("https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/settings", headers=core.mainHeaders(token), data=json.dumps({"status":"dnd"}))
        except:
          pass

      if args == "idle":
        try:
          result = requests.patch("https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/settings", headers=core.mainHeaders(token), data=json.dumps({"status":"idle"}))
        except:
          pass

      if args == "off" or args == "offline":
        try:
          result = requests.patch("https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/settings", headers=core.mainHeaders(token), data=json.dumps({"status":"invisible"}))
        except:
          pass
      print(result)

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Misc(bot))
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback in the question.

Comment: You already asked this question yesterday and apparently deleted it again or something similar. Please refrain from this behavior and wait for an answer to your question, even if it might take a little longer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.